# Setting up php-sdk-gae with symfony2

Tags: php, google-app-engine, symfony

I'm trying to run symfony2 with a hello world sample bundle inside php-sdk-gae.

I'm following the instructions provided in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/ and I can run the demo with the development controller (i.e: configuring app.yaml as following:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /bundles
  static_dir: helloWorld/web/bundles

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: helloWorld/web/favicon.ico
  upload: helloWorld/web/favicon.ico

- url: /.*
  script: helloWorld/web/app_dev.php
```

It works fine, and I am able to get a Hello World after running the server and load /hello/World page

But when I try to run it with the production controller (app.php instead app_dev.php), I get an internal server error.

```
Request URL:http://mysite.local:8080/hello/World
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

The only clue is in the console window where I launched the server, showing the lines ...

```
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.15
Content-type: text/html
```

If I make some changes in app.php files, I realize that it works fine with following AppKernel loading lines:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

But not with the default configuration for the production enviroment ('prod',false).

I'm launching GAE server with this command:
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/home/jon/php-sdk-gae/php-5.4.15/installdir/bin/php-cgi helloWorld/

I'm new in GAE, and I wonder Where can I find logs to get some more information about this error.

Comment: please provide some parts of your app/logs/prod.log. the http 500 should be caused by an exception in production... which one?

Comment: which version of symfony are you using?

Comment: I'm using symfony 2.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is also a problem with caching.

Maybe the problem is this, I've tried in localhost a project with developement version, all right. And when it's deployed to GAE it fails.

Maybe that helps.
http://www.ideato.it/planet-ideato/symfony2-su-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 3):

There is an uncaught exception in your production environment. Thats the reason for the http 500 error.

Let me quickly explain [AppKernel::__construct](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L79)

```
$kernel = new AppKernel($environment, $debug);
```

The first argument is the environment , the second one is the debug option.

If you set debug to true , symfony will try to catch exceptions and show you a nice stracktrace.

This covers the first and the third case where you **don't** get the http 500 error ( caused by an uncaught exception ).

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Now you state the error is NOT thrown in dev environment with debug set to false.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);
```

This means in dev environment there is **no exception**.

Now you have to check the production log file to find out which exception has been thrown.

Use tail -f to see the live changes made to that file in your shell ( i.e. bash ) or if not available open the file in your editor and look for exceptions at the end.

```
tail -f app/logs/prod.log
```

In the symfony2 standard edition logfiles can be found at

```
app/logs/%kernel.environment%.log
```

... with %kernel.environment% being one of dev/prod/test

Comment: I've tried to dive in this logs (logs/prod.log & logs/dev.log), but, when I force the error, there is no line in prod.log

When I run kernel in dev mode, there is some lines in dev.log, but no error lines, because there is no error in dev enviroment. It shows the "Hello World!" message sucessfully. I suspect there is some action in production enviroment that can't be done with GAE (something like caching files or stuff like this)

Comment: please make sure your route outputting Hello World! is not only configured in routing_dev.yml - can you confirm this?

Comment: I can confirm this. It is in routing.yml. It works with AppKernel('prod',true) configuration, but not with AppKernel('prod',false)

Comment: have you tried out your project with a local apache/nginx installation and can confirm that it works with AppKernel('prod', false) there?

Comment: It works in apache accesing vía:     http://mysite.local/app_dev.php/hello/World or http://mysite.local/hello/World (it doesn't work with http://mysite.local/app.php/hello/World because of changes in .htaccess in sf2.2)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with **.htaccess** file shipped with Symfony 2.2

I can use without any problem an application in symfony 2.0, and my application with Symfony 2.2 also works if I replace the web/.htaccess file shipped with Symfony 2.2 with the one shipped with Symfony 2.0

Maybe it is something related with the change made in order to avoid duplicate content (/app.php/something and /something), because since Symfony 2.2, /app.php redirects (301) the request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the lack of write support on the filesystem imposed by GAE. Also, symfony seems to rely on tempnam() function that's disabled in versions lower than 1.9.18 which is not public available at the moment I'm writing this.